# Show that $(\Bbb{N}, |)$ is a distributive lattice.

Tags: lattice-orders, integer-lattices

Show that the set of Natural numbers with divisibility form a distributive Lattice where 
for any $x, y\in\mathbb{N}$  we have $x\wedge y = \operatorname{gcd}(x,y)$ and $x\vee y=\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$?

I totally have no clue about this question..

Comment: Show us what you tried.  This sounds like it's a just question to make you think about the definition.  Write out which equations would have to be true for this statement to be true and see if they are.

Comment: I tried to show that (N,/) doesn't contain the figure M5 but it useless to me because I use particular naturals not general .....

Comment: I tried to show that (N,/) doesn't contain the figure M5 but its doesn't work because I use particular numbers.

Comment: Got it.  That's an interesting thought, but I agree it's kind of a dead end, or at least it doesn't illuminate anything to me.  Try just writing out what being a distributive lattice would mean.  For example, what does it mean for join to distribute across meet in this lattice?

Comment: Hint: use prime decompositions.

Comment: What is the figure M5?

Comment: M5 is Hasse diagram for a non-distributive lattice with tree points that have the same supremum and the same infimum

Comment: I had no clue about prime decomposition @ user87690_

Answer (score 2):

To show distributivity its enough to show always
$$a\vee t=b\vee t, a\wedge t=b\wedge t\to a=b$$
here we have
$$(a\vee t)(a\wedge t) = at$$

Comment: Yes That is it a∨t=b∨t,a∧t=b∧t→a=b means the Lattice doesn't contain M5 figure (a∨t)(a∧t)=(b∨t)(b∧t)→at=bt→a=b hence it distributive lattice thank you